# Cypress - How to avoid writing duplicate steps in different tests?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have 2 tests:

First:
Login-> Go to page A-> click on a checkbox A -> click on button A - >do an action.

Second:
Login -> Go to page A-> click on a checkbox A -> click on Button B -> do an action.

Since Login, Go to page A and click on checkbox A are identical steps..

Me scenario goes way more complex than this:

i have 3 commands:

1 - i have to do a complete flow of a checkout for e.g but here using discount code'

My first 5 steps

the 6th step i use the discount code

My 7-10 steps

2 - : i have to do a complete flow of a checkout for e.g but here not using discount code'
My first 5 steps are same as in A

i have a 6th step saying i wont be using discount code  and do the calculation and stuff

7-10 same as in A

3- i have to do a complete flow of a checkout for e.g but using a payment method which will apply some discount'
My first 5 steps are same as in A

i have a 6th step saying i would choose the payment method  and do the calculation and stuff

7-10 same as in A
}

For the timebeing i am having to put 1, 2 and 3 as 3 separate commands but i am seeing a lot of repetitive steps.

I want to know if this test can be put in one command just the specific criterias goes in a different command and i can call them when i want. All these commands needs to be used in an it tests in my specs.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command can take parameters to change it's test sequence as required.

With parameters you can compose the command to suit different parts of the test.

#### Update from additional details

This is my rough outline of how those details will fit this pattern.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('applyDiscount', (discountCode) => {
  cy.log('applyDiscount', discountCode)
})

Cypress.Commands.add('applyPaymentMethod', (paymentMethod) => {
  if (paymentMethod === 'DiscountForCash') {
    cy.applyDiscount('5%')
  } else {
    cy.log('applyPaymentMethod', paymentMethod)
  }
})

Cypress.Commands.add('paymentFlow', ({discountCode, paymentMethod}) => {
  cy.visit('pageA')                    // fixed step
  cy.get('item-to-purchase').check()   // fixed step

  // variable steps and actions
  if (discountCode) {
    cy.applyDiscount(discountCode)
  }
  if (paymentMethod) {
    cy.applyPaymentMethod(paymentMethod)
  }
})

it('Scenario 1', () => {
  cy.paymentFlow({discountCode: '10%'})
})

it('Scenario 2', () => {
  cy.paymentFlow({paymentMethod: 'Card'})
})

it('Scenario 3', () => {
  cy.paymentFlow({paymentMethod: 'DiscountForCash'})
})

it('Scenario 4 - both optional steps ', () => {
  cy.paymentFlow({discountCode: '10%', paymentMethod: 'DiscountForCash'})
})
```

---

#### Typescript command definitions

The custom commands can remain the same, but for typescript add a type definition file.

Since `paymentFlow()` parameters are optional, define them with `?` to tell typescript they may not be passed in.

**cypress/support/index.d.ts**

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    applyDiscount(discountCode: string): any
    applyPaymentMethod(paymentMethod: string): any
    paymentFlow(object: {discountCode?: string, paymentMethod?: string}): any
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  // other configuration

  "types": ["cypress/support/index.d.ts"],   <-- add reference to above types
  "include": ["**/*.ts",]
}
```

This is the running test log for proof of concept:

[image]

Comment: Hello, i have edited my question..Can you please advise how i can proceed with the above scenario?Thank you

Comment: Ok, I have a better idea of what you are doing, let me see if I can update.

Comment: Thank you..
I have added the code but it is saying Property 'paymentMethod' is missing in type if i am not adding paymentMethod cause in my case i will add paymentMethod in another it. [Note i am using typescript]..How can i cater for this please.Thank you

Comment: Ok, you tagged the question with `javascript` not `typescript`. I will update the code to typescript. Please remember this is only a *rough example of the pattern*, since your question is difficult to follow and there is no existing code to work with.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

[You can use Cypress' `beforeEach()` functionality](https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-before-beforeeach-after-aftereach) to execute a set of commands before each test runs.

```js
describe('My tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // login
    // go to page A
    // click checkbox A
  });

  it('clicks button A', () => {
    // click button A
    // other actions
  });

  it('clicks button B', () => {
    // clicks button B
    // other actions
  });
});
```

This is most useful when running the same tests in a shared `describe` or `context` block.

If your tests will be in separate `describe`/`context` blocks or in separate spec files, [you may want to consider creating a Cypress custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Syntax) to be re-used in different files.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('myFunction', () => {
  // login
  // go to Page A
  // click checkbox A
});

describe('My First Tests', () => {
  it('clicks button A', () => {
    cy.myFunction();
    // click button A
    // other actions
  });
});

describe('My Second Tests', () => {
  it('clicks button B', () => {
    cy.myFunction()
    // clicks button B
    // other actions
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello, My bad..i should have given my proper use case.i have edited my question..Can you please advise how i can proceed with the above scenario?Thank you